# Understanding and writing callback in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});
```

I know what to do with above code but I want to up my level so I can know how is it look like at the back.

my guess is below

```
var app = {

get:function(first, second){
first=  function(){
//do something
},
second = return second(){

}();
}

}
```

I'm sure my guess is wrong btw..

Comment: Please clarify what exactly it is you're asking. I don't see a clear problem statement in this question, nor do I even see a question mark.

Answer (score 0):

Callbacks are used to handle async issues, an example would be:

```
var first = function (callback) {
  var hi = reallyLongFunction();
  return callback(hi);
};

var second = function () {
  first(function(hiFromFirstFunction) {
    //scope of this function has hiFromFirstFunction and anything within the second function
  });
};
```

Comment: how do u call second()?